# Mean Squared Error in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean, mean-square-error

Is there a method in numpy for calculating the Mean Squared Error between two matrices?

I've tried searching but found none. Is it under a different name?

If there isn't, how do you overcome this? Do you write it yourself or use a different lib?

Comment: `((A - B) ** 2).mean(axis=ax)`, where `ax=0` is per-column, `ax=1` is per-row and `ax=None` gives a grand total.

Comment: If you formulate that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: This answer is not correct because when you square a numpy matrix, it will perform a matrix multiplication rathar square each element individualy. Check my comment in Saullo Castro's answer. (PS: I've tested it using Python 2.7.5 and Numpy 1.7.1)

Comment: Also just as a note for anyone looking at this in the context of neural networks, you should sum the error, not average. Averaging the error will give you incorrect gradient values if you try to do grad checking (unless you account in backprop for the average, which is more work than it's worth)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can use:

```
mse = ((A - B)**2).mean(axis=ax)
```

Or

```
mse = (np.square(A - B)).mean(axis=ax)
```

- with `ax=0` the average is performed along the row, for each column, returning an array
- with `ax=1` the average is performed along the column, for each row, returning an array
- with omitting the ax parameter (or setting it to `ax=None`) the average is performed element-wise along the array, returning a scalar value

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, but I think if you do (MatrixA - MatrixB) ** 2 it will try to perform a matrix multiplication, which is different than square each element individually. If you try to use the following formula with a non-square matrix, it will raise a ValueError.

Comment: @renatov in a Numpy array this formula will be applied element-wise so that no matrix multiplication is performed

Comment: @Saulo Castro, I've just tested and I must insist that the result will not be element-wise. I'm using Python 2.7.5 and Numpy 1.7.1. I created the matrix "a" and squared it usign the following commands: `a =  numpy.matrix([[5, 5], [5, 5]])` and then `a ** 2`. The result is the numpy matrix `matrix([[50, 50], [50, 50]])`, which shows that numpy matrix multiplication will **not** be element-wise.

Comment: @renatov maybe you misunderstood me, using a `np.ndarray` will do an element-wise multiplication for `a**2`, but using a `np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix` will do a matrix multiplication for `a**2`...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you were using numpy.matrix.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you're comparing 2 uint matricies, this will not work because the difference will have negative numbers.  You'll need to make int copies before hand (`Acmp = np.array(A, dtype=int)`)

Comment: `np.nanmean(((A - B) ** 2))` if missing values

Comment: The first solution looks like numpy array syntax too, but it is not (see comment by Saullo Castro), so this very specific starting assumption (using a np.matrix) needs to be part of the answer, otherwise it is really misleading.

Comment: Is it possible to have an MSE between two 2D arrays that is equal to 263.562.

Answer (score 51):

This isn't part of `numpy`, but it will work with `numpy.ndarray` objects. A `numpy.matrix` can be converted to a `numpy.ndarray` and a `numpy.ndarray` can be converted to a `numpy.matrix`.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mse = mean_squared_error(A, B)
```

See [Scikit Learn mean_squared_error](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) for documentation on how to control axis.

Answer (score 38):

Even more numpy

```
np.square(np.subtract(A, B)).mean()
```

Comment: Btw this way is equivalent to the Sci-kitLearn function, nice!

Answer (score 9):

Just for kicks

```
mse = (np.linalg.norm(A-B)**2)/len(A)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative to the accepted answer that avoids any issues with matrix multiplication:

```
 def MSE(Y, YH):
     return np.square(Y - YH).mean()
```

From the [documents](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.square.html) for `np.square`:

```
Return the element-wise square of the input.
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard numpy methods for calculation mean squared error (variance) and its square root (standard deviation) are `numpy.var()` and `numpy.std()`, see [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html#numpy.var) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html). They apply to matrices and have the same syntax as `numpy.mean()`.

I suppose that the question and the preceding answers might have been posted before these functions became available.

**Remarks on statistics**
To answer the comment made by @Drew :
This answer is equivalent to the top answers in this thread. Technically, MSE differs from variance in that it uses "true" value of the parameter, rather than its estimate, see
[What's the difference between the variance and the mean squared error?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/140536/110833) and [What is the Difference between Variance and MSE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357738/765359). The two quantities then differ by the *bias* of our estimate of the central parameter. However, when calculating *sample variance*, as is done in the OP, we cannot really know the value of this parameter. I believe the OP uses term *MSE* in a loose sense.

Furthermore, the numpy functions proposed above allow  for parameter `ddof` (the number of degrees of freedom), which allows to obtain unbiased variance estimates (contrary to what is claimed in [some superficial comparisons between python and R](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E_0YtqfUcAgNKJ3?format=jpg&name=small).)

Comment: MSE and variance are not the same unless the mean is zero (i.e., unless A and B have the same mean so that A-B has mean zero in the calculations above).

Answer (score 0):

What about this to keep with the `np.operation` style?

```py
mse = np.mean(np.square(A - B))
```

Just keep in mind that `np.mean()` with no `axis` keyword argument specified will output a scalar, just like `np.sum()`.