# Calculate a trace of large matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix X and I need to write a function, which calculate a trace of matrix [image].

I wrote a next script:

```
import numpy as np
def test(matrix):
    return (np.dot(matrix, matrix.T)).trace()

np.random.seed(42)
matrix = np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 1))

print(test(matrix))
```

It works fine on small matrix, but when I try to calculate on large matrix (for example on matrix with shape `(50000, 1)`), it gives me a memory error.

I tried to find a solution to the problem in other questions on the site, but nothing helped me. I would be grateful for any advice!

Comment: How about : `matrix.T.dot(matrix)`?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927586/memory-error-while-performing-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number you're trying to compute is just the sum of the squares of all entries of `X`. Sum the squares instead of computing a giant matrix product full of entries you don't want:

```
return (X**2).sum()
```

Or ravel the matrix and use `dot`, which is probably faster for contiguous `X`:

```
raveled = X.ravel()
return raveled.dot(raveled)
```

Actually, `ravel` is probably faster for non-contiguous `X`, too - even when `ravel` needs to copy, it's not doing *more* allocation than `(X**2).sum()`.

Comment: Now I feel silly for immediately reaching for `einsum` before thinking about it. ;-)